# Issue on launching AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Studio and trying to launch AVD for sample application. I am getting following error on launching AVD. I am using Android Studio 2.2.2. What is the workaround to solve this problem?

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: ERROR: Unfortunately, there's an incompatibility between HAXM hypervisor and VirtualBox 4.3.30+ which doesn't allow multiple hypervisors to co-exist.  It is being actively worked on; you can find out more about the issue at http://b.android.com/197915 (Android) and https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294 (VirtualBox)
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Internal error: initial hax sync failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have Docker running. If so, quit Docker.
See here https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-using-docker-for-mac-with-android-emulator-haxm/8939

Answer (score 1):

For me it was `VirtualBox` which is conflicting with running `emulator`. After killing `VirtualBox` I was able to run `emulator`.